# Why I get error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

Why do I get error

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

in

```
let SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
```

in the following code:

```
func SpawnRain() {
    Rain = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rain")
    let MinValue = self.size.width / 8
    let MaxValue = self.size.width - 40
    let SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
    Rain.size = CGSize(width: 32, height: 32)
    Rain.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
    Rain.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Rain.size)
    Rain.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Rain
    Rain.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Player
    Rain.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Rain.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

let action = SKAction.moveToY(-70, duration: 8.0)
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    Rain.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))
    self.addChild(Rain)
}
```

Comment: First of all, please follow code formatting conventions, at least when sharing code. Variables are starting lowercase by convention, as do function names. Secondly, are you sure that float you are calculating is never negative? If self.size is `0.0f`, like before the initial layout, this feeds a negative number to the constructor of an unsigned integer.

Comment: UInt32 is unsigned so what you could do is 
        let maxValue = self.size.width > 0 ?  self.size.width - 40 : 0

Comment: Presumably, `MaxValue - MinValue` is not in range for a `UInt32` and therefore you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the width is small, then MaxSize - MinSize < 0, and for security reasons trying to convert a negative number to UInt32 will crash. That's part of the design of Swift. In a less safe language, arc4random_uniform would return an enormous large value that can only cause trouble and lead to a hard-to-find error.